# how to skip queryselectorall does not exist or null

Tags: javascript, if-statement, null, schema

```
for (i = 0; i < document.querySelectorAll('span.movie-cast-title').length; i++)
{
  if (document.querySelectorAll('span.gcharacter')[i].innerText, == 'null') {
    continue;
  }
  data.actor.push({
    "@type": "PerformanceRole",
    "actor": {
      "@type": "Person",
      "name": document.querySelectorAll('span.movie-cast-title')[i].innerText,
      "url": document.querySelectorAll('a.movie-cast-url')[i].href,
    }
    "characterName": document.querySelectorAll('span.gcharacter')[i].innerText,
  });
}
```

how to skip queryselectorall does not exist or null
"characterName": document.querySelectorAll('span.gcharacter')[i].innerText

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the index, that is, `i` is within the bounds of querySelectorAll:

```js
if(i >= document.querySelectorAll('span.gcharacter').length) {
    continue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the element exists, not the `innerText`. Because if the element doesn't exist, you can't get its `innerText`.

```
if (!document.querySelectorAll('span.gcharacter')[i]) {
    continue;
}
```

Comment: this method is working but it's take wrong value examle span.movie-cast-title i=0, span.gcharacter j=0. 0,0. span.movie-cast-title i=1, span.gcharacter i=1 does not exist so the value add  span.gcharacter i=2 0,2. i want 1; and  span.gcharacter i=2, span.gcharacter i=2 2,2 ; ---- 0,0; 1; 2,2

Comment: also i am try if else method its not working https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70397020/how-to-skip-queryselectorall-does-not-exist-or-null

Answer (score 0):

wouldn't it be clearer to use a forEach?

```js
const 
  spCharacters = document.querySelectorAll('span.gcharacter')
, aMovieCast   = document.querySelectorAll('a.movie-cast-url')
  ;
document.querySelectorAll('span.movie-cast-title').forEach( (sp,i) =>
  {
  if (spCharacters[i].innerText !== 'null')
    {
    data.actor.push(
      { '@type' : 'PerformanceRole'
      , 'actor' :
        { '@type' : 'Person'
        , 'name'  : sp.innerText,
        , 'url'   : aMovieCast[i].href,
        }
      , 'characterName': spCharacters[i].innerText
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: it error for , or phase

Comment: do you always express yourself by enigma?

Comment: also i am try if else method its not working https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70397020/how-to-skip-queryselectorall-does-not-exist-or-null

Comment: "not working" is not an answer, don't you want to add a significant HTML part of that ?